# Prove a function to be analytic by dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, analyticity

> Given $f \in L^1$, prove that
>   $$F(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t-z}\,dt$$
>   is an analytic function and $$F'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{f(t)}{(t-z)^2}\,dt.$$

My attempt:
It is sufficient to prove its analytic by showing that the derivative of $F(z)$ exists. (Any flaws with this argument?)

\begin{align}
F'(z)&=\lim_{\Delta z_n\to 0} \frac{F(z+\Delta z_n) - F(z)}{\Delta z_n}\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z_n\to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta z_n} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \left[\int^\infty_{-\infty} \left( \frac{f(t)}{t-(z+\Delta z_n)}-\frac{f(t)}{t-z} \right) dt \right]\\
\mbox{(a bit algebra)} &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \lim_{\Delta z_n\to 0}   \int^\infty_{-\infty}  \frac{f(t)}{(t-z)(t-z-\Delta z_n)} \, dt \\
\end{align}

I came so close to justify the exchange of the limit with the integral (Hence, DCT). I somehow cannot find a appropriate $g\in L^1$ to bound the integrand.

Comment: For $z \notin\mathbb{R}$, choose $|\Delta z_n| < |\Im z|/2$. Then $|t-z-\Delta z_n| \ge |t-z| - |\Delta z_n| \ge |t-z|-|\Im z|/2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z$ is not real, you can always bound the denominator away from zero, and so you can use $f(t)/(t-z+\delta)^2$ for an appropriate (and small enough) $\delta>0$.

But when $t$ is real I see problems: for instance let $f$ be any $L^1$ function that is constant on some interval around $2$. Then 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(t)}{t-2}
$$
doesn't exists (it blows up at $2$).

Are you really supposed to show that $F$ is analytic on all of the complex plane?

Comment: How about if I restricted the domain to $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{z\}$?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Then you can use the distance from $z$ to the real axis to bound $t-z$ away from zero.

Comment: From your hint, I think the correct one should be $$ g(t) = f(t) / (t-z-\delta)^2 ,$$ since it needs to satisfy |(the ingetrand)|$\le g(t)$, am I right?

Comment: Yes, with  $\delta=\text {Im}z/2$.